# Proving that $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{\sqrt{a^{2} {\cos^{2}}(x) + b^{2} {\sin^{2}}(x)}} = \frac{\pi}{2 \cdot \text{AGM}(a,b)} $.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I know Neumann’s solution of this famous definite integral that is totally based on substitution, but is there any solution using complex analysis? Assuming that $ a > b $, show that
$$
  \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}{x}}{\sqrt{a^{2} {\cos^{2}}(x) + b^{2} {\sin^{2}}(x)}}
= \frac{\pi}{2 \cdot \text{AGM}(a,b)},
$$
where $ \text{AGM}(a,b) $ is the [arithmetic-geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) of $ a $ and $ b $, which satisfies the following functional equation:
$$
\text{AGM}(a,b) = \text{AGM} \! \left( \frac{a + b}{2},\sqrt{a b} \right).
$$

Comment: Are you seeking a solution that does not use [Landen's transformation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landen%27s_transformation)?

Comment: @sos440 The problem is that i don't know much about elliptic integrals.I am doing a course on this in my current semester.I am mainly interested in "contour integral" typr proof,if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let
$$I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 x+b^2\cos^2 x}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(a^2 t^2 + b^2(1-t^2))}}.\tag{1}$$
Obviously $I(a,a)=\frac{\pi}{2a}$, hence in order to prove our identity we just need to prove that:
$$ I(a,b)=I\left(\sqrt{ab},\frac{a+b}{2}\right).\tag{2}$$
By replacing $b\tan x$ with $z$, we have:
$$ I(a,b) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{(z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2)}}.\tag{3}$$
By Lagrange's identity for multiplying the sums of two squares,
$$ (z^2+a^2)(z^2+b^2) = (z^2-ab)^2+(a+b)^2 z^2, \tag{4} $$
hence, with the substitution $z=\frac{1}{2}\left(u-\frac{ab}{u}\right)$, $(3)$ turns into
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{du}{\sqrt{\left(u^2+\frac{1}{4}(a+b)^2\right)(u^2+ab)}}=I\left(\sqrt{ab},\frac{a+b}{2}\right),$$
so we're done, since $I(a,b)$ is a continuous function with respect to its parameters and the iterates of the map $\varphi:(a,b)\to\left(\sqrt{ab},\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$ converge towards $\left(\text{AGM}(a,b),\text{AGM}(a,b)\right)$ giving:
$$ I(a,b)=\frac{\pi}{2\cdot\text{AGM}(a,b)} $$ 
as wanted.

Comment: You just need to prove *that* and some continuity of $I$ with respect to its parameters.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: $(2)$ *is* proved through $(4)$, and the continuity with respect to $a$ and $b$ is quite trivial.

Comment: It is quite trivial but it has to be proved (or at least mentioned!) for your nice argument to be complete — this may be not equally obvious to everyone watching.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Ok, I take that suggestion to make a small edit.

Comment: Your second change of variables is incorrect (very frustrating to anyone trying to check it). Please use correct letters in the correct order. Your $x$ was an angle variable so don't reuse it for something else in the second change of variables.

Comment: @KCd: thanks for pointing that out, now fixed.

Comment: +1.Dear @JackD'Aurizio thank you for your answer.Your solution is "similar" to Neumann's solution, which I already know.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question but it is too long for a comment.

As far as I can remember, it starts with $$I=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x)}}=\sqrt{2}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(a^2-b^2\right) \cos (2 x)+(a^2+b^2)}}$$ and the integration leads to an elliptic integral given by $$I=\frac 1a F\left(x\left|1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right.\right)=\frac 1b F\left(x\left|1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right.\right)$$ Using the bounds, the definite integral is then $$J=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x)}}=\frac 1a {K\left(1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)}=\frac 1b {K\left(1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)}$$ and I suppose that Legendre functional relation is then used to get the result.

I am sorry for not being of more help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !your "solution" uses some high machinery like elliptic integral that i don't know.